# Length of a service name can exceed documented length of a registry key name

Tags: winapi, windows-services, registry, limit, msdn

I am wondering why the maximum length of a registry key name is 255 characters while the maximum for a service name is 256, what is the rationale behind it?
(Note that those length specifications are w/o the \0 terminator).

This is weird given that the Service Control Manager stores its service information in the registry.

Plus my own tests show that it is indeed possible to create:

- services having names with 256 characters, using the `CreateService` API.
- registry keys having names with 256 characters as well, using the `RegCreateKeyEx` API.

This "phenomenon" is also observed by others, e.g. like described in this [blogpost](https://www.sepago.com/blog/2010/07/20/how-long-can-a-registry-key-name-really-be).

Both limits are documented at Microsoft's documentation sites:

- "[Registry Elements Size Limits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724872(v=vs.85).aspx)"

  > *Key name*: 255 characters
- As part of the [`CreateService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450(v=vs.85).aspx) Windows API

  > *pServiceName*: The name of the service to install. The maximum string length is 256 characters. [...]

Comment: With and without \0 terminator?

Comment: @Anders No, both limits are w/o \0 terminator. Tested with `CreateService` and `RegCreateKeyEx`. I updated my question to mention my tests with the latter.

Comment: @eryksun Both string types, \0-terminated C strings and UNICODE_STRING, don't impose any restriction on the string length, so I don't see how your argument could explain the difference? I updated my question to mention my tests with `RegCreateKeyEx`.

Comment: I checked in a debugger, and `RegCreateKeyEx` includes the trailing NUL character in the string's `MaximumLength`, not the `Length`, which makes sense. So it has no problem using the full 256 characters allowed in an NT Key name. With that, I'd say this is either a documentation bug or maybe a legacy from Windows 9x if it limited Key names to 255 characters.